# LoginButton Facebook with appcompat-v7:22.1.1

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-appcompat

Has anyone try using appcompat-v7:22.1.1 with facebook login sdk version 4.0.0 I tried that but Failed,and I dont know how to fix it, when I try using different layout it works, but when using layout that contain LoginBUtton From facebook it does not work, here is my code  :

my Activity looks like this :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import santana.gujarat.chatmeet.R;

/**
 * Created by root on 14/05/15.
 */
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback {


    private static final List<String> permissionNeeds= Arrays.asList("user_photos", "friends_photos", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends");

    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private GraphRequest request;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_login_activity);

        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.facebook.samples.loginhowto",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissionNeeds);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                loginResult.getAccessToken();

                request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), LoginActivity.this);
                request.executeAsync();

                Log.d("FB Granted", loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions().toString());
                Log.d("FB Denied", loginResult.getRecentlyDeniedPermissions().toString());
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Log.d("Error Login",e.getMessage());

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse response) {
        Log.d("resultFB", user.toString());
        try {
            Log.d("resultFB",user.getString("username"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }

    }

}
```

My Manifest :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:name=".AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activity.LoginActivity" />


        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

My layout :

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the Logcat Error  :

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
           ..
     Caused by: null
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at santana.gujarat.chatmeet.activity.ListPeopleActivity.onCreate(ListPeopleActivity.java:18)
...
```

Comment: try to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()); before setContentView();

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but still not working

Comment: Just saw that you don't have an FB App id specified in manifest.Try to set it like this <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/fb_app_id"/> (where fb_app_id is the ID of an app created on https://developers.facebook.com)

Comment: is it just me or the docs of facebook api is not telling me to do that, where can I find the sample, cuz the docs pretty not telling the whole thing?

Comment: Yeah.. I had the same problems as you at first: I missed the part where I had to insert some stuff in Manifest. Here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/ you'll find te things that needs to be done first. Afterwards call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()) before setContentView() and it should work

Comment: The stacktrace doesn't line up with your code, case by `ListPeopleActivity`, yet your code about `LoginActivity`. I would test this first on Facebook sample project (e.g. HelloFacebookSample) and see if that works and take it from there.